How to delete just the parent Element in DOM using cheerios
Following is the file structure
<ABCList>
<ABC>
    <RL>3166</RL>
    <Client>42@gmail.com</Client>
<TravelerList>
        <Traveler>
            <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
            <LastName>zyz</LastName>
            <EmailAddress>xyz@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
            <PhoneNumber>5145845</PhoneNumber>
        </Traveler>
    </TravelerList>
</ABC>
</ABCList>

I want to to remove just  from the file structure and keep the rest as it is. Following is what i have tried and it is removing just to parent element but it removes parent and child.
$("ABCList").remove()


I will update the question and remove the first solution as i was not trying to remove the attribute. the structure is far complex but i copied part of it . but will modify to add more structure but basically i want to remove root element

$("ABCList").remove() will remove the element and all it's descendants. I don't know cheerio, but in jQuery we'd use unwrap

I think you're looking for unwrap:
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<ABCList>
<ABC>
    <RL>3166</RL>
    <Client>42@gmail.com</Client>
<TravelerList>
        <Traveler>
            <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
            <LastName>zyz</LastName>
            <EmailAddress>xyz@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
            <PhoneNumber>5145845</PhoneNumber>
        </Traveler>
    </TravelerList>
</ABC>
</ABCList>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html, {xml: true});
$("ABCList ABC").unwrap();
console.log($.html());

Output:
<ABC>
    <RL>3166</RL>
    <Client>42@gmail.com</Client>
<TravelerList>
        <Traveler>
            <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
            <LastName>zyz</LastName>
            <EmailAddress>xyz@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
            <PhoneNumber>5145845</PhoneNumber>
        </Traveler>
    </TravelerList>
</ABC>

This is in my Cheerio Cheatsheet: "Lift children up to a parent".
It's less optimal, but $("ABCList").replaceWith($("ABCList").html()); is also possible.
Since Cheerio shares most of its API with jQuery, see also remove parent element but keep the child element using jquery in HTML.

Thanks @ggorlen. It worked with unwrap.
